# проблема chrome v103. смена браузера?

Tags: google-chrome, chromedriver, microsoft-edge

Стоит ли переходить на использование другого браузера (к примеру microsoft edge) из-за проблемы в chrome v103? Подробнее: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/10799

Comment: Почему бы не перейти на Chrome 102, например?

Comment: Собственно, в комментариях по вашей ссылке уже и предложили так сделать https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/10799#issuecomment-1172194912

Comment: понижал до 102 - то же. запускаю с профилем.